# How to connect two 2x4 to 4x4 post base?

Tags: framing, deck, woodworking, decking

I am looking for a way to use a 4x4 base to carry two joined 2x4s as in the picture below.

The problem is that there is a 0.5 in. gap as the actual width of the two boards is 1.5+1.5 = 3 in. while the base width is 3.5 in.

I see someone used a pad to fill in the gap as shown in the picture below. Any idea what kind of pad to use to fill in that gap?
Thanks!
[image]

This is the base:
[image]

Comment: To what end?  Why? What function will the two 2 x 4’s be performing?  The “pad”  in the photo is probably just a piece of half-inch plywood.

Comment: The "end" is keeping the beam stable in the base. Is this not obvious? Doesn't really matter what the beam is for.

Comment: isherwood.  to what end is a phrase meaning "for what purpose"  https://www.definitions.net/definition/to%20what%20end   How or what is the two 2x4 used may have a bearing ( pun intended ) on how to answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd normally use whatever material the beam is compose of. In this case, you probably have some treated lumber scraps. There you go.